# Why does this script just gives me 1 ouput (strpos PHP)

Tags: php, search, strpos

Im creating a socialnetwork, and this script is a search function.

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$search = $_POST['search'];
//strpos($user,$search)
$path = "../database/users";
$users = scandir($path);
$output = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($users as $user) {
    if ("$user" !== ".." || "$user" !== "." | "$user" !== "$username") {
        if(strpos($user, $search)) {
            $count = $count + 1;
            array_push($output, $user);
    }

}
```

}

Now im wondering why it gives me just 1 value in the output array... wenn there are more users with the a in it (it gives me none output when i search for more than one).

Comment: if ("$user" !== ".." || "$user" !== "." || "$user" !== "$username") {

I think you missed out |?

Answer (score 1):

strpos might return 0, which is valid (means the string starts with the search phrase), but it will not pass the `if(strpos($user, $search))` check.

Consider adding `if(strpos($user, $search) !== false)`.

Also remove the bitwise or `|` and replace it with a logical or `||`.